# Storing Current Page for PDF eBooks

Tags: windows, pdf, android, bookmarks, pdf-reader

I am reading through several PDF eBooks on 2 different Windows PCs and 1 Android tablet.  I would like to come up with an easy way to "bookmark" my current page that will work on all environments.  So if I set my last page while reading the PDF on a Windows PC, then I start reading the same book later on the Android tablet, I would like for the Android tablet to remember what the last page was.

Some of these eBooks are secured PDFs, so I don't think I can rely on the standard PDF bookmarks functionality.

Has anyone found a good way to do this?  Perhaps store the PDFs out in the cloud and use PDF readers on the PC and Android that keep the current page in sync?

Or perhaps it would be easier to convert the PDF to some other format and then bookmark it?

Comment: "Perhaps store the PDFs out in the cloud and use PDF readers on the PC and Android that keep the current page in sync?" - Why store the PDFs themselves in the cloud? As long as identical files are stored on both machines, an app with versions for both OSes might be able to store just the current page number online and sync across devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking to do this, Google Play Books now has an option that appears to work pretty well.  You can upload PDF files to Google Play Books, and then read those PDFs using an Android app or online through your browser.  And Google Play Books supports bookmarks that work across platforms.

Read more here: 
[Google Play Books Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3097151?hl=en)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you very much for that.  I had no idea!  This is a perfect option for me.

Comment: It doesn't support Audio Books. The text of my PDF's look blurry (I'm sure they are texts and not images).

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question.
I know for myself on PC I am using standard Adobe Reader with the "Remember page" option enabled, and the PDFs themselves are located in my DropBox or Google Drive folder.
It automatically keeps them in sync across all 3 PCs that I use regularly.
I haven't tried it on Android yet, I dunno if the Adobe Reader for Android has that option, but I will try to test it out today to see if it does as well.

UPDATE: Tested it on Android, the Adobe Reader, QuickOffice, and Polaris apps don't support the remember page feature.